# load data on the all member in icCube

Tags: iccube

The all member in a dimension in icCube has no key. 
But for a specific case I need to load data on this level.

How can I do that?

Note: if I have a NULL value, the 'unknown member' property is fired, and I do not want that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you've this scenario, you will have a parent/child dimension associated. Then you can just define de first level as being the 'all member' and keep the key as well.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it is a multi-level dimension. As a work-around I could add a new member for this purpose in the hierarchy.